# ¿Es posible evitar que json_encode cambie los caracteres acentuados?

Tags: php

Yo estoy generando un JSON desde una consulta a la base de datos. Al obtener los datos los guardo en un array y luego les aplico `json_encode` para crear un objeto JSON.

Todo funciona bien, pero quiero saber si es posible evitar que `json_encode` cambie los caracteres acentuados.

Por ejemplo, me crea datos así:

```
"antifona": "\u00c1breme los ojos, Se\u00f1or, y contemplar\u00e9 las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
...
```

Yo quiero mis datos con sus acentos, pues ya los tengo validados, por lo que no necesito que `json_encode` me genere mis valores así.

¿Se puede hacer eso de alguna manera? Estuve revisando en el Manual de PHP y no vi que se hiciera mención de esa posiblidad.

Yo quisiera el siguiente resultado:

```
"antifona": "Ábreme los ojos, Señor, y contemplaré las maravillas de tu voluntad.",
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es posible luego de la version de PHP 5.4 en la cual a esta funcion se le agrego el parametro `"JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE"` por ende deberias tener algo como esto;

```
json_encode( $mis_datos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Documentacion: https://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: En efecto, funciona. Muchas gracias Albert.

Comment: creo que igualmente no importa que te cambie los caracteres, cuando haces luego el encode o los recuperas con JS no se ven afectados y te lo devuelve con acentos. Mas que nada lo hace por si tienes que transportar la información. Estos tipos de caracteres dan problemas al pasarlos, por codificación. Un saludo!